# git pushing to remote branch is throwing error

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit, git-push

I have created a branch from remote repository and changed the local repo name. Later I have removed the tracking by running the `git branch --unset-upstream` command. 
Now when I try to push my local changes to the remote branch I am getting the below error

```
git push --set-upstream origin feature/my_remote_branch

error: src refspec feature/my_remote_branch does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://pradeep@bitbucket.comp.com/scm/app/app.git'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Ofcourse you are getting this error if you are using --unset-upstream. Read the documentation carefully.

Comment: I update the git push command in my question. Still getting the same error

Comment: What is the name of the local branch, what is the name of the remote branch?

Comment: The error message `error: src refspec feature/my_remote_branch does not match any` means Git does not believe that *you* have a branch named `feature/my_remote_branch` in the first place. It has not even called up another Git yet, it's saying "I don't know of any branch with this name."

Comment: local branch name is `feature-one-branch` and remote branch name is `refs/heads/feature/my_remote_branch`

Comment: If the local branch is named `feature-one-branch`, then you must use that name in the refspec. (A refspec can have the form local-name:remote-name, i.e., two branch names with a colon in between. The name on the left is the *source* and the name on the right is the *destination*. For push, the source is your name and the destination is theirs. For fetch, the source is their name and the destination is your name.)

Comment: It's relatively rare, and usually not a good idea, to use a *different* name in your repository (as the source) from the one you will use in the other repository (as the destination), as it is too easy to get confused about which one to use when. Rather than using this more complex refspec format, it's probably better to *rename* your local branch first. You can then use the push without the colon form, and Git will assume "same name on both sides" once you have done the first `git push -u`.

Comment: It worked when I did the `git push origin --set-upstream origin:feature/....` with the `origin:` before the `feature`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `git push -u <remote> <local-branch>:<remote-branch>`

```
$ git push -u origin feature-one-branch:my_remote_branch


Or, (if not works)
$ git push -u feature my_remote_branch
```

Answer (score 0):

As your local and remote branches have different names, you need to specify both on the push command as long as you do not have the tracking set accordingly.

`git push --set-upstream origin feature/my_remote_branch` tries to push the local branch `feature/my_remote_branch` to the remote which you don't have locally.

You should have called

```
git push --set-upstream origin feature-one-branch:feature/my_remote_branch
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are pushing for first time try

```
git push  origin -u feature/my_remote_branch
```